# Error de conexión JSP con MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, java-ee

estoy haciendo pruebas con JSP y MySQL a través de un sencillo form que cree con Bootstrap.

No logro validar el usuario y contraseña de mi pagina jsp,  el form lo tengo en   `index.jsp` que hace referencia a `login.jsp` este último se encarga de conectar con la DB y validar los datos ingresados por el usuario en el form dentro de `index.jsp`

código de `index.jsp`

```html
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
<link  href="bootsrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
<link  href="bootsrap/css/estilospropios.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="cuadro" action="login.jsp" method="post">
  <form class="login" >
   <img class="mb-4"
    src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg"
    alt="" width="72" height="72">
   <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Inicia sesión</h1>
   <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label> 
   <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="nombreUsuario" placeholder="NickName" required="" autofocus=""> 
   <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label> 
   
   <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="contraUsuario" placeholder="Password" required="">
   <div class="checkbox mb-3">
   
    <label> <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
     Recuerdame
    </label>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Entrar</button>
   <a id="a1" href="Registrar.jsp"> O Registrate</a>
   <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">Nombre Empresa © 2017-2018</p>
   
  </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

código de `login.jsp`

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

  <%
   //Obtengo los valores del form y los guardo en 2 variables
   String nombre= request.getParameter("nombreUsuario");
   String contrasena= request.getParameter("contraUsuario");
   
   //Cargo el driver
   Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
   
   //Url de conexion a la DDBB
   Connection miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evento","root","");
   
   //Creo mi statement y ejecuto la consulta SQL para verificar los datos del usuario
   Statement miStatement=miConexion.createStatement();
   String instruccionsql = "SELECT * FROM usu WHERE nickname_usu='"+nombre+"' AND pass_usu='"+contrasena+"'";
   miStatement.executeQuery(instruccionsql);
   
   //Si esto devuelve algo...
   out.println("logueado con exito");
   
   
  %>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTAS
- Ya cargue el controlador JDBC a las librerías JAR , 
- el controlador lo tengo dentro de la carpeta WEB-INF -> lib , 
- También referencie la ubicación del controlador dentro del build path del proyecto.
- Ya probé la consulta SQL en el phpMyAdmin y dio ok,
- Todos los `archivos.jsp` se encuentran dentro de Web Content

Comment: es mala practica utilizar la conexion en tu archivo jsp, deberias realizarlo en una clase de java.

Comment: Gracias, la idea final es crear un servlet y una clase. Por el momento estoy haciendo pruebas así. No entiendo porque no conecta ya que pasó todas las pruebas que hice.

Comment: la conexion lo realiza correctamente? o el logeo es donde esta el problema?

Comment: Creo que no esta conectando ya que use varios println para ver donde se trancaba y no ejecuto ninguno. Pero no se si directamente al hacer clic en login en el formulario no le esta dando pelota al action="login.jsp"

Comment: intenta realizarlo desde la vista principal, una prueba. donde compruebes la conexion si esta abierta. algun status